# Ansicon vs. Batch File

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch-file, ansi

I am attempting to make a colored command prompt in Windows 7.

Using ansicon, I have successfully managed to create the prompt.  However, when I put the commands into a batch file, I receive an error.

These are the commands that I am using:

```
ansicon -p
chcp 65001
prompt $e[1;31m█$e[1;32m█$e[1;34m█$e[1;33m$_$d $t$_$e[1;37m$p$g
```

Below is an image that shows the contents and execution of the batch file, and the error that occurs when executing the `prompt` command *within* the batch file.  It also shows the manual execution of the commands, and the resulting command prompt.

[image: Ansicon batch failure]

How can I get the commands to properly execute from a batch file?

Comment: Why not just use Powershell. Then you could format the prompt however you wanted in the profile.

Comment: My guess is that ansicon is failing to hook into the cmd.exe process for the batch file execution. `-p`  What happens when you run `ansicon -p` on the command line and then run the bat file containing the `chcp` and `prompt` commands?  [ANSICON Documentation](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/blob/master/readme.txt)

Comment: @EBGreen - I'll give that a try.

Comment: @DavidRuhmann - Just tried your suggestion, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to get the batch file to work correctly, so I ended up taking @EBGreen's suggestion and using PowerShell.  I *did* have to run the command `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` in PowerShell to get my profile to run, however.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used ansicon, and I don't know why your batch script is giving different behavior then the command line.

But give this a try in your batch script:

```
ansicon -p
chcp 65001
for /f "delims=" %%A in ("$e[1;31m█$e[1;32m█$e[1;34m█$e[1;33m$_$d $t$_$e[1;37m$p$g") do prompt %%A
```

Comment: I still receive the same error.